# How to have netlify to point to some other html in another folder?

Tags: netlify

I have a project for which the structure is like
-src(folder)
-static(folder)
-package.json
-package-lock
-webpack.config

my main index.html is in the src folder - src/index.html.
Is this the reason why when I click on the website I get "Page Not Found
Looks like you've followed a broken link or entered a URL that doesn't exist on this site." ?
If yes then how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
Add a "netlify.toml" in your root folder along with your package.json etc files with this code-

```
[build]
  base ="/"
  publish = "src/"
```

pointing the publish folder to the folder with index.html file.